# WooCommerce product import metadata bag

Tags: woocommerce

I am managing a large product database using a Google sheet, which is then exported as a CSV. All works fantastic, apart from some custom metadata. It is being correctly imported into Advanced Custom Fields, however each product must be re-saved to reflect on the front end. As it is a large catalogue this is quite a big task.

Is this a WC bug, or is there a workaround I might have missed?

When updating other fields, including attributes, pricing etc, all changes are immediately reflected.

Many thanks,
Pete

Comment: I'm curious to know what type of ACF you have taken(repeater, text etc...). If you could show me some code that save correctly into meta table with screenshot of DB how that save in to table. Also, give me one more screenshot of meta table after you re-saved that from wp-admin (I guess you re-saved from there).

Comment: datasheet is not a good idea to store a big number of rows, it's more slow than MySql DB, alternativally you can create a custom plugin with a cron task to import data from datasheet into WP database using the wordpress and ACF native function